# "response" prediciton with earth (MARS) and caret in R

Tags: r, regression, r-caret

I hope this is not too naive of a question.
I am performing a series of binomial regressions with different models in the `caret` package in R.  All are working so far except for earth (MARS).  Typically, the `earth` family is passed to the `glm` function through the `earth` function as `glm=list(family=binomial)`.  This seems to be working ok (as evident below).  For the general `predict()` function, I would use the `type="response'` to properly scale the prediction.  The examples below show the non-caret approach in `fit1` with the correct prediction in `pred1`.  `pred1a` is the improperly scaled prediction without `type='response'`.  `fit2` is the approach with `caret` and `pred2` is the prediction; it is the same as the non-scaled prediction in `pred1a`.  Digging through the `fit2` object, the properly fitted values are present in the `glm.list` component.  Therefore, the `earth()` function is behaving as it should.

The question is... since the `caret` `prediction()` function only takes `type='prob' or 'raw'`, how can I instruct is to predict on the scale of the response?

Thank you very much.

```
require(earth)
library(caret)
data(mtcars)

fit1 <- earth(am ~ cyl + mpg + wt + disp, data = mtcars,
        degree=1, glm=list(family=binomial))
pred1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = mtcars, type="response")
range(pred1)
[1] 0.0004665284 0.9979135993 # Correct - binomial with response

pred1a <- predict(fit1, newdata = mtcars)
range(pred1a)
[1] -7.669725  6.170226 # without "response"

fit2ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
fit2 <- train(am ~ cyl + mpg + wt + disp, data = mtcars, method = "earth", 
         trControl = fit2ctrl, tuneLength = 3,
        glm=list(family='binomial'))
pred2 <- predict(fit2, newdata = mtcars)
range(pred2)
[1] -7.669725  6.170226 # same as pred1a

#within glm.list object in fit4
[1] 0.0004665284 0.9979135993
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few things:

- the outcome (`mtcars$am`) is numeric 0/1 and `train` will treat this as a regression model
- when the outcome is a factor, `train` will assume classification and will automatically add `glm=list(family=binomial)`
- with classification and `train`, you will need to add `classProbs = TRUE` to `trainControl` for the model to produce class probabilities.

Here is an example with a different data set in the `earth` package:

```
library(earth)
library(caret)

data(etitanic)

a1 <- earth(survived ~ ., 
            data = etitanic,
            glm=list(family=binomial),
            degree = 2,       
            nprune = 5)

etitanic$survived <- factor(ifelse(etitanic$survived == 1, "yes", "no"),
                            levels = c("yes", "no"))

a2 <- train(survived ~ ., 
            data = etitanic, 
            method = "earth",
            tuneGrid = data.frame(degree = 2, nprune = 5),
            trControl = trainControl(method = "none", 
                                     classProbs = TRUE))
```

then:

```
> predict(a1, head(etitanic), type = "response")
      survived
[1,] 0.8846552
[2,] 0.9281010
[3,] 0.8846552
[4,] 0.4135716
[5,] 0.8846552
[6,] 0.4135716
> 
> predict(a2, head(etitanic), type = "prob")
        yes         no
1 0.8846552 0.11534481
2 0.9281010 0.07189895
3 0.8846552 0.11534481
4 0.4135716 0.58642840
5 0.8846552 0.11534481
6 0.4135716 0.58642840
```

Max